# How can I use a Java String method (split) directly from Kotlin source?

Tags: kotlin

Doing some profiling, it seems my bottleneck is the Kotlin `kotlin.CharSequence.split()` extension function.

My code just does something like this:

```
val delimiter = '\t'
val line = "example\tline"
val parts = line.split(delimiter)
```

As you might notice, `parts` is a `List<String>`.

I wanted to benchmark using Java's `split` directly, which returns a `String[]` and might be more efficient.

How can I call Java's `String::split(String)` directly from Kotlin source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast a `kotlin.String` to a `java.lang.String` then use the `java.lang.String#split` since `kotlin.String` will be [mapped](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) to `java.lang.String` , but you'll get a warnings. for example:

```
//                               v--- PLATFORM_CLASS_MAPPED_TO_KOTLIN warnings
val parts: Array<String> = (line as java.lang.String).split("\t")
```

You also can use the `java.util.regex.Pattern#split` instead, as @Renato metioned it will slower than `java.lang.String#split` in some situations. for example:

```
val parts: Array<String> = Pattern.compile("\t").split(line, 0)
```

But be careful, `kotlin.String#split`'s behavior is different with `java.lang.String#split` , for example:

```
val line: String = "example\tline\t"

//   v--- ["example", "line"]
val parts1: Array<String> = Pattern.compile("\t").split(line, 0)

//   v--- ["example", "line", ""]
val parts2 = line.split("\t".toRegex())
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot!

Comment: @Renato Not at all. glad it helped you.

Comment: In case anyone uses this, you can suppress the warning with `@Suppress("PLATFORM_CLASS_MAPPED_TO_KOTLIN")`

Comment: @Renato yeah. I want to tell OP that the compiler will produce a warning. :)

Comment: In case anyone wanted to know: Java split is much faster than Kotlin's if you use it millions of times (I was splitting over a million lines and after changing  to Java split, it did the job almost twice as fast). The Pattern solution is much slower even than the Kotlin's split.

Comment: @Renato I agree on. because `java.lang.String#split` has optimized for this internally. however, it is an off-topic in this question.

Comment: It's not off-topic. The only reason you would do this is for performance, so it's good to know it pays off.

Comment: @Renato I admit that `Pattern#split` is an optional way, I'll fix my answer. thanks for your feedback, sir. How about it now?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
(line as java.lang.String).split(delimiter)
```

But it's not recommended to not use the `kotlin.String` as the compiler might tell you.